# My vector elements keep changing themselves after each input

Tags: c++

```
char* name = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char));
    char* highscore = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char));
    char* password = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char));
    player* c = new player(name, highscore, password);
    int i;
    int j = 0;
    int score = 0;
    vector <player*> players;
    vector <char*>* names = new vector <char*>;
    vector <char*>* passwords = new vector <char*>;
    vector <int> scores;
    ifstream input;
    input.open("user.csv");        
    do {
        cout << "Welcome to Champion Yahtzee\n";
        cout << "Player Name            Highest Score\n";
        cout << "-----------            -------------\n";
        while (input.good())
        {
            input >> *c;
            players.emplace_back(c);
            names->push_back(name);
            score = atoi(highscore);
            scores.push_back(score);
            passwords->push_back(password);
            j++;
        }
```

This is my code, I know that in order to input into it we have to expand the vector? at least from what I read to fit in the new char and I genuinely don't know how to fix it. I've tried initializing the vector as  `vector <player*> players;` but that was of no use since after each input it overrode the previous pointers and sets all the elements to the input. How do I go about fixing this?

Comment: You're just changing the same player object each time. Why are you using pointers here? I think you misunderstand their use.

Comment: I'm using pointers because it was specified in the assignment brief, would creating a new player object with each loop fix my problem?

Comment: If it's a requirement of the assignment to use them, then yes, create a new object each iteration of the loop.

Comment: `char* password = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char));` That looks troublesome.  1 `char` is just enough space to hold a null-terminated string of **no more than zero** characters.

Comment: You must be taking a very advanced C++ class.  Third year, I'd expect.

Comment: @ChrisMM ill try that out! thank you

Comment: I'd also recommend using `std:: string` instead of `char` and avoid using malloc.

Comment: @Eljay i wish im year 2, my uni had the bright idea of teaching us basics and like 5 other modules in java and then suddenly decided that the advanced programming concepts should be in c++

Comment: @DrewDormann ah I never thought about that, I will try to use a MAX variable to set the size of it, hopefully that helps I imagine something like
``` int max = 16;``` 
```char* password = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)* max);```

Comment: `while (input.good())` tests if the last read succeeded *after* you've already used the potentially invalid data. You should test the result of the input operation directly.

Comment: C++ is not java. There's nothing in the shown code that requires `malloc`. `malloc` isn't even C++, but C. There is never a valid reason to use `malloc` in C++ code, for a number of reasons.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik we are required to use either that or the new keyword so i might just use new

Comment: @Aurous I am afraid you took a completely wrong approach to tackle the problem.

Comment: @RetiredNinja ah that makes sense, how would you suggest going about that

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ oh, how so?

Comment: @Aurous nearly all of this code looks buggy and very fragile.  I see that **most** of your variables are pointers, but not all are.  How are you deciding whether a variable should be a pointer?

Comment: @DrewDormann just going off a spec provided to me ngl, it was specified that we use cstrings for the username and password but are free to do whatever with the highscore

Comment: Just looks like you are taking an Advanced Class in C++ All About Things You Should Never Do In C++.

Comment: @Eljay LMFAOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO using cstrings in 2021 should be illegal

Comment: Let me focus my question about pointers.  Why is `player *c` a pointer?  Why is `vector <char*>* names` a pointer?  I can't imagine an instructor telling students new to C++ to try so hard to make most variables raw pointers.

Comment: Perhaps more germaine to the appropriateness of a question posted here.  The code you show here [does not compile](https://godbolt.org/z/Pq3Y1PTMz).  It doesn't come close to compiling.  But your question doesn't mention the many errors produced by this code.  Why?

Comment: @DrewDormann Oh that was just a bit of my code that i was struggling with, i didnt want to post the entire thing since itll take too much space, heres a repo of it. https://github.com/aur0us/YahtzeeAssignment

Comment: Hopefully all the lessons after this are "How to avoid pointers". The usual way to structure an input loop would be `while (input >> *c) { /* do stuff with c */ }` but you could also check right after like `if (!input.good()) { break; }`.

Comment: Rather than posting a question here with a comment stating that some of your question is at a different website, consider reading about the importance of a [mre].

Comment: Usually, if your teacher tell you to do something a given way, it is because it has already been teached. If your teacher show you malloc, then he surely explain that you need to specify the maximum size of that string when allocating memory. Then if you have studied `new` (and `new[]`), he surely explain that `new`is better than `malloc` in C++ program. Maybe he want you to use multiple ways to ensure that your understand them all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you are getting the same values everywhere is because you only allocate your storage memory once, then push the same memory address in to your vectors over and over.

Basically, you always have only one object.

To fix this, you must allocate new objects inside the loop, like so:

```
vector <player*> players;
vector <char*> names;
vector <char*> passwords;
vector <int> scores;
ifstream input;
input.open("user.csv");        

cout << "Welcome to Champion Yahtzee\n";
cout << "Player Name            Highest Score\n";
cout << "-----------            -------------\n";
while (input) { //this is the proper way in c++ 11 and up
    char* name = new char[MAX_NAME_LEN];
    char* highscore = new char[MAX_SCORE_LEN];
    char* password = new char[MAX_PASSWORD_LEN];
    player* c = new player(name, highscore, password);
    
    input >> *c;
    players.emplace_back(c);
    names.push_back(name);
    int score = atoi(highscore);
    scores.push_back(score);
    passwords.push_back(password);
}
```

Here are the explanations to changes to your code:

1. Unless there is some weird requirement in your homework, the vectors do not need to be pointers, they only need to *contain* pointers.
2. We allocate new objects at the beginning of every loop, so every time you read in data it will go in to a new place in memory.
3. If you have to use `char *` you should define constants (or macros) like `MAX_NAME_LEN` for maximum length of the `name` field.
   Your homework probably specifies maximum input length for all fields to make things simpler.
4. The condition in the `while` loop is simply the stream object.
   Starting with C++11 it overrides the casting to `bool` to return `true` while more data can be read.
   If you are using older C++ standard use `while (!input.eof())` or check the return value of `input >> *c` and `break` if it is `false`.
5. If you are writing C++ you should use `new` to allocate memory.
   Though `malloc` will work correctly, it is considered to be "the C way" and its use in C++ is discouraged.

Comment: Holy shit thank you so much, ill implement this now and this all makes sense, and yeah i think i went overboard with the vectors, since they only need to contain said pointers so ill try that. Thank you for the feedback!

Comment: `while (input)` still suffers from the issue that if a read fails the incorrect data is consumed, and then the error is checked.